# electron install error : Failed at the electron@1.4.6 postinstall script 'node install.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to install electron recent version and encountering this error. I tried installing `sudo` and did downgrade to electron 1.4.5 but this error persists. node version I'm using is `v7.1.0`

Complete error log

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron@1.4.5" "--verbose"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! electron@1.4.5 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.4.5 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs electron
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the `node` version I'm using. Possibly electron is not compatible with the newer version of node that is released.

I've installed [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and installed a lower version of node. In my case `v6.3.0`. After that I was able to install electron without errors.

Comment: Had the same problem. Fixed by upgrading node and npm. 10x @Penkey Suresh

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue, also when using sudo. 
when i switched to root, the installation worked.